# Android: stopService doesn't call onDestroy

Tags: android, service

I have big problems with stopping a service, which plays audio file. I want to stop the current service before I play another file.

Activity:

```
public void playTrack(View view){       
    Intent i=new Intent(this,playService.class);
    i.setAction("com.c0dehunterstudios.relaxer.PLAY");
    
    if(isPlaying){ 
          stopService(i);   
          isPlaying=false;
          Log.v("ACTIVITY", "Stopping..");
    }
    
    startService(i);
    isPlaying=true;
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
public void OnDestroy(){
    Log.v("SERVICE","Service killed");
    player.stop();
    super.onDestroy();  
}
```

But sadly it doesn't work - actually it doesn't even come down to the "Service killed" inside OnDestroy().

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, it's onDestroy, not OnDestroy . Second, you must use the @Override annotation for compile-time checking, so your Service code should look somewhat like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Log.v("SERVICE","Service killed");
    player.stop();
    super.onDestroy();  
}
```

Comment: Also, if you're using Eclipse (as most people are with Android, I think), try getting into the habit of using the "Source->Override/Implement Methods" menu command -- that will create a stub for the function ready for you to fill in, and you won't be able to make a mistake with the name.

Comment: I use it correctly, but still onDestroy() is not called. :/

Comment: Also I am using it correctly and onDestroy() is not called

Answer (score 14):

First, you need to clarify how many types of services in Android. AFAIK, there are:

- Foreground service.
- Background service.
- Bound service.
- Intent service.

These services stop in different ways.

- **Foreground:** only stop when you intentionally stop it by calling `stopService()` in activity or fragment where you start that service or call `stopSelf()` in its own service. And Please note only these methods trigger service's `onDestroy()`.
- **Background:** `stopService()` and `stopSelf()` do in the same way as foreground. Moreover, you should know this service is in the same thread with activity or fragment calling it, so if you destroy activity or fragment, this service will stop also, but without calling `onDestroy()`. It basically destroys underground. Thus, if you want to catch when this service stops you need to add `android:stopWithTask="false"` when declaring service in Manifest file like this:

  ```
  <application>
      //....
      <service android:name=".services.catchingStopService" 
           android:stopWithTask="false" /> 
      //....
  </application>
  ```

  And now in your service class, you can override this method which triggers whenever this service stops:

  ```
  @Override 
  public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
      super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent); 
      // Your job when the service stops. 
  }
  ```
- **Bound:** you need to handle by your self by `bindService()` and `unbindService()`, you will find out it's totally the same as `starService()` and `stopService()`
- Intent: this type of service stops by itself when it finishes its jobs. And you can use `ResultReceiver` to communicate between service and activity or fragment. It's similar to `BroadcastReceiver`. You can search for example on Google easily.

Summary: base on your purpose, pick the type of service satisfying you. And they all agree with:

- Don't count on `onDestroy()` to know when service stops because it
  sometimes gets called underground; more accurately, onDestroy calls
  when stopService() or stopSelf() calls (BoundService works in the
  same way, I think, but by a similar method, maybe unBind(), I did not
  test yet).
- Use attribute android:stopWithTask="false", instead to know when the
  service really stops.
- All types of service stop when the device shutdown or OS kills it if
  device leaks of memory.
- You also should have a look at flag return by `onStartCommand()` to
  be able to deal with when services stop like restart service again or
  something. Here are some keyword you can search:

  - `START_STICKY`
  - `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`
  - `<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />`
  - `<actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />`

Comment: It's `stopSelf()`, not `stopItself()`.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem even with onDestroy correctly set up - the answer for which could be useful for people coming to this page. For me, onDestroy was not called immediately during stopService, sometimes for a very long time - leaving the service doing work when it should have stopped.

The answer is that this is expected behaviour - I can guess but don't exactly know why. So my solution in this case was to create a public static method to stop the actions of the service manually, which happens at the time it's called, then stopService() will call onDestroy in it's own good time...

In the case for this example (which is probably long gone, I would probably decide to keep the service running until it's expected to quite the app, but provide ways to change audio file, while the service is still active.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was printing a log inside the onDestroy and It was not printing the log and I thought onDestroy not calling when I call stopService. but in **Android studio many times does not print the log** so you can once **double check or verify with the debug or toast**.