# stopService() doesn't call onDestroy

Tags: android

I have a VpnService class and I call 
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyVpnService.class)) 
It didn't call onDestroy(), when I manually stop vpn from notification it called onDestroy

[Android: stopService() doesn't call onDestroy()!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086371/android-stopservice-doesnt-call-ondestroy)
There is someone asked the same question, but it is different from my situation, I override onDestroy correctly

Or how can I stop a VpnService?

Comment: Could you provide us with some code?

Comment: You are using IntentService or Service? IntentService runs separatedly for each requisition, while Services have a lifecycle and can be stoped.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I'm using VpnService which extends Service