# Android service stopSelf() not stopping the service

Tags: android, android-service

I have started a service for recording location at a particular time interval. I am using a timer to schedule the time interval at which I am supposed to notify the data. I am finishing the service on logout. I have used fused location provider in the service and I am using a logout broadcast to stop the service

Here is the code in my logout broadcast receiver

```
    mTimerTask?.cancel()
    mTimer?.cancel()
    mTimer?.purge()
    job.cancel()
    stopLocationUpdates()
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(logoutReceiver)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    HomeScreenHelper.setJobListResultObtainedListener(null)
    stopSelf()
```

Here is the stop location updates method

```
private fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient?.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback!!)
    mFusedLocationClient = null
    mLocationCallback = null
    mLocationRequest = null
    Log.d(tag, "Location update stopped .......................")
}
```

After calling the stop self method I am still not able to kill the service and it keeps running in the background. Although the service is killed after I kill the app after logging out. I want the service to be killed as soon as the logout is successful.

The issue is that if the app is not killed then the service thread keeps running but doesn't check for any updates, but if a user logs in again immediately, then the service restarts on the same thread and uses all the previous data from the previous login session.

I am not sure what is happening and I have been stuck on this issue for a while now.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: May be you are using START_STICKY instead of START_NOT_STICKY

Comment: Yes, @UsmanZafer, I am using START_STICK but I have tried replacing it with START_NOT_STICKY and still, I am getting the same behavior

Comment: How did you determine it isn't stopped? It might just be restarted very quickly.

Comment: @jobbert I have kept logs in onCreate, onStartCommand, onDestroy and in onStopService and after going in onDestroy, there are no new logs.

Comment: @Kartik there is no guarantee that onDestroy is called. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/46335562/2917564 for moren information about how to guarantee if you know the service is stopped.

Comment: @jobbert I have gone through this article while development. The issue is the process is not being ended even after stopSelf() is called. In the Android Studio logcat, I see the process as running even after stopSelf is called

Comment: Good to hear, just clarifying ;) That's why I'm commenting.

Comment: Can you try stopping the service without a broadcast? For example after X time, to exclude the possibility of a threading issue with using a broadcast to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210659/discussion-between-kartik-and-jobbert).